# git diff unique to merge commit

Tags: git, merge, diff, commit

Say I have,

```
      A topic
     / \
D---E---F master
```

I can easily get the diff of D-E by doing

```
git diff D..E --name-status
```

and same for E-F, and E-A.

Commit F is a merge commit, and say it had a conflict.  It was resolved by modifying foo.bar.  foo.bar was git added, then the merge commit was committed.  The merge conflict was resolved.

Now the change for foo.bar exists only in commit F.  How do I get that diff?

Is there a way to get the diff of files that were uniquely introduced in a merge commit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git show` on the merge commit will show changes not in any of its parents. For example:

```
$ echo 123 > file1.txt
$ git add file1.txt
$ git commit -am '123'

$ git checkout -b test
$ echo 1234 > file1.txt
$ git commit -am '1234'

$ git checkout HEAD~ -b test2
$ echo 0123 > file1.txt
$ git commit -am '0123'

$ git merge test
$ echo 01234 > file1.txt
$ git add file1.txt
$ git commit -am 'Merge test'

$ git show
commit f056a1c91d76c8dfce60a03122494dce92c1e161
Merge: 489f1d3 fcfd2bc
Date:   Fri Jul 15 20:30:17 2011 -0500

    Merge test

diff --cc file1.txt
index 40381e2,81c545e..3521a84
--- a/file1.txt
+++ b/file1.txt
@@@ -1,1 -1,1 +1,1 @@@
- 0123
 -1234
++01234
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what "files that were uniquely introduced in a merge commit" means. The file had to exist before, or there wouldn't have been a conflict. And "the change for foo.bar exists only in commit F" isn't exactly correct, either. Commits don't contain changes. You can see the foo.bar diff exactly the same as any other: `git diff E F` or `git diff A F`, depending on which branch you want to follow.